# Type 'X' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly Y[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui, react-hook-form

My end goal for this component is to take data from an API call and output the items into an autocomplete list

The error I'm getting is:

```
Type 'ImportSurveyCompany' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly ImportSurveyCompany[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 18 more.
```

Here are the interfaces:

```
export interface ImportSurveyCompany {
    name: string;
    id: string | number;
}
export interface ImportSurveySources {
    name: string;
    surveyImportSourceId: string | number;
}

export interface ImportSurveyState {
    companies: ImportSurveyCompany[];
    importSources: ImportSurveySources[];
}
```

Here are the redux action creators:

```
    interface ImportSurveyCompaniesAction {
      type: typeof SET_IMPORT_SURVEY_COMPANIES;
      payload: ImportSurveyCompany;
    }
```

Here are the actions:

```
export const setImportSurveyCompaniesData = (
    importSurveyCompaniesData: ImportSurveyCompany,
): ThunkAction<void, RootState, null, ImportSurveyAction> => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const importSurveyData =
                importSurveyCompaniesData as ImportSurveyCompany;
            dispatch({
                type: SET_IMPORT_SURVEY_COMPANIES,
                payload: importSurveyData,
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};

export const getImportSurveyCompaniesData = (): ThunkAction<
    void,
    RootState,
    null,
    ImportSurveyAction
> => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        try {
            const importSurveyData = await getSurveyImportCompanies();
            dispatch(setImportSurveyCompaniesData(importSurveyData));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    };
};
```

This is my reducer:

```
const initialState: ImportSurveyState = {
    companies: [],
    importSources: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action: ImportSurveyAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_IMPORT_SURVEY_COMPANIES:
            return {
                ...state,
                companies: [...state.companies, action.payload],
            };
        case SET_IMPORT_SURVEY_SOURCES:
            return {
                ...state,
                importSources: [...state.importSources, action.payload],
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

and my API call:

```
export const getSurveyImportCompanies = async () => {
    return ApiRequest('/api/companies?enable=1&pagination=0', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    })
        .then((res) => {
            const companies: Array<ImportSurveyCompany> = [];
            res.data['hydra:member'].map((key, value) => {
                return companies.push({ name: key.name, id: key.companyId });
            });
            return companies;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return err;
        });
};
```

The form component:

```
const { companies, importSources } = useSelector(
        (state: RootState) => state.importSurvey,
    );

<Controller
   name="company"
   control={control}
   render={({ field }) => (
      <Autocomplete
         {...field}
         id="company"
         style={{ width: 300 }}
         options={companies[0]}
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ here is where it complains
         onChange={(event, value: any | null) => {
           setValue('company', value.id);
         }}
         defaultValue={null}
         getOptionLabel={(option: any) =>
             `${option.id} - ${option.name}`
         }
         renderInput={(params) => (
           <TextField
               {...params}
               label="Selectionner un adherent"
               variant="outlined"
               error={!!errors.company}
               helperText={errors.company?.message}
            />
           )}
       />
    )}
/>
```

And the form stuff

```
 interface ImportFormValues {
        file: any;
        company: ImportSurveyCompany | null | undefined;
        source: ImportSurveySources | string | null;
        note: string;
    }

    const {
        control,
        register,
        setValue,
        getValues,
        formState: { errors },
        handleSubmit,
    } = useForm<ImportFormValues>({
        resolver: yupResolver(ImportValidationSchema),
    });
```

I'm beyond stumped as to why it's saying that. Any light to be shed on the problem would be very welcome.